# Python (3.9) reading specific characters at a specific line in a file?

Tags: python, string, file, file-handling

I can't figure out how to read specific characters at a specific line in a text file; here's what I tried:

File('save1.txt') content:

```
line 1 | level : 1

line 2 | life : 20
```

My code:

```
#vars
level = 0
life = 0

#open file in read mode
save = open('save1.txt', 'r')

#setting reader vars
lreader = save.readlines()
creader = save.read()

#changing my vars to their value in the save
level = lreader[0]
level = int(creader[8:])
life = lreader[1]
life = int(creader[7:])

#returning my vars
print(level)
print(life)

#just pausing to see :)
input()
```

Then I get errors or even no output sometimes, but never what I want.
It would be really helpful if I could join the 'lreader' and the 'creader' vars on the same lines *and* get it to work.

Comment: If you `.readlines()` into `lreader`, then the "cursor" is at the end of the file and `.read()` returns an empty string. `level = lreader[0]` *is* how you access a specific line in a file, it's unclear why you then try to overwrite that value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I get it, but then, how can I attribute the value to my var by precising the line and the characters I want on the same line of code?

Comment: `lreader[line index][character index]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep. Bunch of thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Well @jonsharpe showed me that it was easier than I thought, so thanks to him, I just did this:

```
#vars
level = 0
life = 0

#open file in read mode
save = open('save1.txt', 'r')

#setting reader vars
lreader = save.readlines()

#changing my vars to their value in the save
#I put minus 1 on the level var because apparently it outputs with the \n at the end
level = lreader[0][8:-1]
life = lreader[1][7:]

#returning my vars
print(level)
print(life)

#just pausing to see :)
input()
```